# Error with link code

Tags: html, hyperlink

having some trouble with some html

i post link: https://twitter.com/AtomicCockroach

but when i run the page it comes up with

https://twitter.com/AtomicCockroach%E2%80%8E

sample code:

```
<li>
<a href="https://twitter.com/AtomicCockroach‎" target="_blank" id="style3">
<span>
<img border="0" src="/images/social_icons/t.png">
AC Twitter
</span></a>
</li>
```

Thanks :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure there are no "non-printed" characters between last character in link and `"`。 Perhaps you copied it from somewhere alongside with some characters that are not displayed in your editor.

You can do it by removing last character and `"` by pressing delete key or backspace and then entering them again manually.

Source: been there.

Comment: I tested the code pasted into StackOverflow by sticking it through a URL encoder and this indeed seems to be the issue.

Comment: @randak simple copy/paste issue. After a few years of coding you more appreciate typing everything manually instead of copying and then spending hours debugging ;)